# Can I drop the type instantiation from an instance of a class with an associated type family?

Tags: haskell, types, type-families

I have this code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilyDependencies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DefaultSignatures #-}

module Study where

class C a where
    type T a = r | r -> a
    pred :: T a -> Bool

    default pred :: T a ~ [a] => T a -> Bool
    pred = not . null

instance C Integer where
    type T Integer = [Integer]
```

It works like this:

```
λ Study.pred [1,2,3]
True
λ Study.pred ([ ] :: [Integer])
False
```

I would like to reduce minimal instance definitions simply to:

```
instance C Integer
```

— Unless I want specifically to diverge from the pattern.

Most of the instances I plan to have should be default, with `T a ~ [a]`, but some do need their
own `T` type. I am reluctant to tolerate numerous identical trivial definitions like the given
one. What can be done?

Comment: In the unlikely event that this is not a minimized example: since you don't mention `a` alone anywhere in the class (only `T a`), consider `class C a where pred :: a -> Bool`; it requires no fancy extensions, and is no less powerful (thanks to the `r -> a` annotation on your associated type).

Comment: @DanielWagner Even though it is minimized severely, I could actually use your advice. You see, I have two kinds of methods in my class: "connecting", that have both `a` and `T a` in their signature, and "isolated", that only have `T a`, but never `a`. (E.g. `pred` would be isolated.) Now, I can put all the isolated methods in a class `C`, and then put the connecting methods in a two-parameter subclass `C ta => B a ta`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just add a default type instantiation:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilyDependencies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DefaultSignatures #-}

module Study where

data One a = One a

class C a where
    type T a = r | r -> a
    -- This looks a bit strange,
    -- because it looks like T is defined twice
    -- but that's not actually the case
    type T a = [a]
    pred :: T a -> Bool

    default pred :: T a ~ [a] => T a -> Bool
    pred = not . null

instance C Integer

instance C Char where
  type T Char = One Char
  pred = const True
```

---

```
*Study> :t undefined :: T Integer
undefined :: T Integer :: [Integer]
*Study> :t undefined :: T Char
undefined :: T Char :: One Char
```